# 'int' object has no attribute 'find_all' while scraping data from a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting a `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find_all'` exception, even though the value of `table` isn't empty:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
data = []
Url = 'http://www.svcengg.com/course_offered.php'
pageHtml = uReq(Url)
soup = soup(pageHtml,"html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", { "width" : "470","height":"212"})
#print(table) 
for x in table:
    table_body = x.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.find_all('td')
        for td in cols:
            data.append(td.text.strip())
    print(data)
```

Comment: That must mean that `tr` or `table_body` is a number. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over a single `table` element:

```
for x in table:
```

Iteration over an element will include *text* nodes, as well as other elements. For the given URL, the first element in `table` is a string:

```
>>> list(table)[0]
'\n'
```

Calling `find()` on a string produces an integer (as you are calling the [`str.find()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), not the BeautifulSoup `Element.find()` method).

So `table_body = x.find('tbody')` assigns `-1` to `table_body`, because there is no such string `tbody` in the string `'\n'`. And integers have no `find_all()` method.

Don't use iteration over a single element. You already found the table, there is just no such table, or 1:

```
if table is not None:
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
```

Note however, that there is *no `<tbody>` element in the HTML input*. Browsers insert a standard `<tbody>` element if it is missing, but BeautifulSoup does not. Even if there was a `<tbody>` element in the HTML, you can still look directly for `<tr>` table rows from the table element too. Skip looking for the `tbody`, there is no need.

This works:

```
if table is not None:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.find_all('td')
        for td in cols:
            data.append(td.text.strip())
```

For the given URL, `data` then contains:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data)
['Electronics  & Communication Engineering',
 '120',
 'Computer Science & Engineering',
 '120',
 'Information Science & Engineering',
 '60',
 'Mechanical Engineering',
 '120',
 'Electrical & Electronics Engineering',
 '60',
 'Civil Engineering',
 '120']
```